# I cannot figure out how to print the even numbers

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ from a book I got 2 days ago, one of the exercises in it is confusing me. I feel like I did it right but the book did not teach me this. Can someone tell me what to do with my code to make it print only the even numbers from a(user inputted) and b(user inputted).

```
int a, b;

cout << "What number would you like to start counting at?" << endl;
cin >> a;

cout << "What number would you like to end at?" << endl;
cin >> b;

while (a <= b){
    if (a % 2 == 0){
        cout << a << endl;
        a++;
    }
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Consider what happens if "a" is an odd number. Does the loop ever reach the next number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increase `a`'s value even when it is not even :

```
int a, b;

cout << "What number would you like to start counting at?" << endl;
cin >> a;

cout << "What number would you like to end at?" << endl;
cin >> b;

while (a <= b){
    if (a % 2 == 0){
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    a++;
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only increments `a` if `a` is even, that's not good, you want the `a++` in the `while` loop, but outside the `if a is even`